# filter vertices on number of outgoing edges in gremlin titan in java

Tags: java, gremlin, titan

I want to query and filter all vertices with more than 500 outgoing edges in titan using gremlin in java...how do i do this?I have started off as below

```
    pipe=pipe.start(graph.getVertices());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You then need a filter function

```
p.start(
  g.getVertices()
   .filter(new PipeFunction<Vertex,Boolean>() {    
             public Boolean compute(Vertex v) {
               // write your logic here to count edges on the vertex and 
               // return true if over 500 and false otherwise
             }));
```

Using GremlinPipeline in Java is described more [here](https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin/wiki/Using-Gremlin-through-Java#making-use-of-gremlinpipeline-in-java)