# Get result as a sub graph rather than vertice : Gremlin - orient-db

Tags: graph-databases, gremlin, orientdb

Hi : I am a neebie in Gremlin and Orient-db. I was playing around with Gremlin and orient db in java. I was able to query my vertices and edges using the available methods and get the results.I am using back("Alias-name") to get the result vertices of my query.

My question is can I get a graph of all the result vertices ( the related graph and the information of the result) since right now I am able to get the vertices but I want the entire "sub graph" information of my resultant vertices in the same query.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is a code with generic example:

```
GremlinPipeline startPipe = pipe.has("friend-name", "friend-name")
            .in("friend-depends").as("friend-depends")
            .outE("resource-depends").inV()
            .has("resource-name", "car")
            .back("friend-depends");

v(Friend)[#15:13]
v(Friend)[#15:7]
v(Friend)[#15:12]
```

The results are right but I would like to get the results as

```
Friend#15:13{friend-name:Frank,Friend-type:Personal,in_depends:#17:10 (friend of friends),... with edges} v2
```

Thanks,
Sabari

Comment: hey, i wanna help u out the with the first post. You must illustrate them with the code where you are with general example. So, that they help you out where you need to extend or correct. It makes life of answerer easier and you too get quick response too

Comment: Just giving a verbal description like this is very vague. You need to give people context and examples. Please read this [advice on how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Be sure to follow the link at the bottom to Jon Skeet's blog post [Writing the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx). Pay special attention to the "Golden Rule", though I highly advise you to read the entire article.

Comment: Thanks for the response .I have updated my question with my code / generic example .

Answer (score 1):

Gremlin does not provide an explicit `subgraph` function (as of the unreleased 2.5.0).  The only way to get a subgraph with Gremlin is to explicitly extract those graph elements yourself.  My preference is to simply `sideEffect` the elements to an in-memory TinkerGraph.  You can see an example here:

http://gremlindocs.com/#recipes/subgraphing

Given your amended question, you may use the the `path` step to get individual parts of the path as in:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerGraphFactory.createTinkerGraph();
==>tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6]
gremlin> g.v(1).outE.inV.path
==>[v[1], e[9][1-created->3], v[3]]
==>[v[1], e[7][1-knows->2], v[2]]
==>[v[1], e[8][1-knows->4], v[4]]
gremlin> g.v(1).outE.inV.has('age',T.gte,31).path
==>[v[1], e[8][1-knows->4], v[4]]
```

That looks a bit like what you are looking for.  From there you could `sideEffect` to a subgraph. From there you could choose to not use `back` anymore:

```
gremlin> g.v(1).outE.inV.has('age',T.gte,31).path.sideEffect{println it}.collect{it.last()}
[v[1], e[8][1-knows->4], v[4]]
==>v[4]
```

or stick with it:

```
gremlin> g.v(1).as('x').outE.inV.has('age',T.gte,31).path.sideEffect{println it}.back('x') 
[v[1], e[8][1-knows->4], v[4]]
==>v[1]
```

Comment: Stephen: Thanks a lot for your response . I am new to gremlin and I see very less Java documentation of the api over the web. As i have mentioned in my above java query , how do i implement sideeffect / path in java to get the entire sub graph. Thanks again !

Comment: I would suggest you get familiar with Gremlin in general before delving too deeply into how to express it in Java, but you basically just need to supply a `PipeFunction` in the place of a groovy closure to get compliant with Gremlin Java.  this example (http://stackoverflow.com/a/22899380/1831717) shows a `filter` in Java, but you could do the same with the `sideEffect` step.

Comment: Hi stephen : I have added a generic example with side effect code in java so i can get help out of that in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22971382/subgraphs-using-sideeffects-gremlin-orientdb-java . Thanks for your help with this !